# How to write debian/changelog to allow build package other people

Tags: package-management, compiling, bazaar

I've created simple debian package which I am building using `bzr bd`.

the problem is my colleague is unable to build this package using this method, without changing changelog's email to her own, so the gpg signing passed.

We are working together on the same project and want to have possibility to build this package for each own.

---

I am not using debuild to build package - only bzr bd. And this is my private package not in launchpad.

Any idea?

Comment: You can pass additional flags on to `debuild` through `bzr bd` by using `--` So, the command from the deleted answer becomes: ``bzr bd -S -- -k0x67B68654``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### the -k solution

When building a debian package you can switch the signing of a package to be your own PGP key via the -k parameter.

For example:

```
bzr bd -S -- -k0x67B68654
```

will build the package but will use the PGP key `67B68654`

Obviously - change the `67B68654` to your launchpad OpenPGP key:

[image]

Comment: Works! I've used my key from `passwords & keys` in Ubuntu and it is OK. But 1 more question: how to get this identifier using script (bash).

Comment: how to get your PGP key via bash?  Good question to ask - please hit that "Ask Question" button. Cheers.

Comment: Something like: `gpg --list-sigs | grep -m1 "sig.*email@host.com" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 3` ;)